# SQL Join country city community show record even without match

Tags: mysql, join

I have been trying to get this on MySQL.

They are stored in 3 different tables (country, city, community) and they can be joined together by country.country_link = city.country_link and city.city_link = community.city_link

[image]

And sometimes need to add country filter as well like below

I have tried this but still no avail:

```
SELECT
tbl_country.country_link AS country_link,
    tbl_city.city_link as city_link,
    tbl_community.community_link
FROM
tbl_country
LEFT JOIN
tbl_city ON tbl_country.country_link = tbl_city.country_link
LEFT JOIN
tbl_community ON tbl_city.city_link = tbl_community.city_link
WHERE
tbl_city.country_code = 'AE'
UNION
SELECT
tbl_country.country_link AS country_link,
    tbl_city.city_link as city_link,
    tbl_community.community_link
FROM
tbl_country
LEFT JOIN
tbl_city ON tbl_country.country_link = tbl_city.country_link
LEFT JOIN
tbl_community ON tbl_city.city_link = tbl_community.city_link
WHERE
tbl_city.city_link IS NULL AND
tbl_community.community_link IS NULL AND
    tbl_city.country_code = 'AE'
UNION
SELECT
tbl_country.country_link AS country_link,
    tbl_city.city_link as city_link,
    tbl_community.community_link
FROM
tbl_country
LEFT JOIN
tbl_city ON tbl_country.country_link = tbl_city.country_link
LEFT JOIN
tbl_community ON tbl_city.city_link = tbl_community.city_link
WHERE
tbl_community.community_link IS NULL AND
tbl_community.community_link IS NULL AND
    tbl_city.country_code = 'AE'
```

Comment: Move conditions in where clause to Table Joining conditions, since you are using LEFT JOIN and you are trying to use same LEFT JOINED table in where clause then this change the purpose of LEFT JOIN. Eventually it becomes INNER JOIN.

Comment: Can you show some sample? Coz I tried it and I am not getting the result that like in the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per above comment I have made the changes in your sql script. Observer the WHERE clause conditions which are now moved at joining level conditions.

```
SELECT tbl_country.country_link AS country_link,
       tbl_city.city_link as city_link,
       tbl_community.community_link
FROM tbl_country
LEFT JOIN tbl_city ON tbl_country.country_link = tbl_city.country_link AND tbl_city.country_code = 'AE'
LEFT JOIN tbl_community ON tbl_city.city_link = tbl_community.city_link

UNION
SELECT tbl_country.country_link AS country_link,
       tbl_city.city_link as city_link,
       tbl_community.community_link
FROM tbl_country
LEFT JOIN tbl_city ON tbl_country.country_link = tbl_city.country_link
LEFT JOIN tbl_community ON tbl_city.city_link = tbl_community.city_link AND
          tbl_community.community_link IS NULL AND tbl_city.country_code = 'AE'

UNION
SELECT tbl_country.country_link AS country_link,
       tbl_city.city_link as city_link,
       tbl_community.community_link
FROM tbl_country
LEFT JOIN tbl_city ON tbl_country.country_link = tbl_city.country_link
LEFT JOIN tbl_community ON tbl_city.city_link = tbl_community.city_link AND
                           tbl_community.community_link IS NULL AND 
                           tbl_community.community_link IS NULL AND
                           tbl_city.country_code = 'AE'
```

Comment: How do you filter it for per country though? Coz it still shows other combination after the uae records